# how to assign enum to viewmodel property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, enums

main classes:

```
public enum FooType
{
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue
}

public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public FooType Type { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

View models:

```
public class FooVM
{
  public FooType Type { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to select the one's I want using Linq

```
_fooService.All().Select(x => new FooVM
             {
               FooName = x.FooName,
               Type = x.Type, // I'm having trouble with this guy. Says I cannot implicitly convert it.
              }
        );
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Namespace.Type' to 'Namespace.ViewModel.Type'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

I'm having an issue of converting it. But I have no idea what should be done. What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This LINQ query is run on which collection?

Comment: My bad. I edited my post. It runs on `Foo`

Comment: Also post full error.

Comment: Guess you're right. How should you assigned `enum` to a ViewModel?

Comment: `..Name = x.Name..`?? `Foo` does not have a property `Name` (did you mean `x.FooName`?

Comment: I am so sorry. Typo.Edited my post

Comment: @BoyPasmo: ViewModel is also a class. You can definitely assign Enum in a ViewModel. Please post full error.

Comment: Edited my post with full error. Having `cast` issues.

Comment: Have you included a definition for `enum FooType` in 2 separate namespaces?

Comment: Yes I have. But still, don't know why what's wrong. Really no idea.

Comment: Remove the definition for `enum FooType` from your `ViewModels` namespace - its not necessary (and that's whats causing the conversion problem) - just add a using statement in `ViewModels` that points to the initial definition.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so that's how. many thanks. really new to C#. think you could post it in the answer section so that I could mark it as correct. And it would be great if you provide more explanation for other's reference. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message suggests you have defined `enum FooType` in both `Namespace` and `Namespace.ViewModels`, thus an implicit conversion cannot be made between them.  I suggest you remove the definition from `Namespace.ViewModels` and just include a reference to `Namespace` in `Namespace.ViewModels` (using statement) or cast the type as suggested by [Trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196823/trevor-pilley)

Answer (score 2):

The error suggests that you have an enum called `Type` in 2 separate namespaces which even if you have the same values, are still different.

```
namespace Namespace.Type
{
    public enum FooType
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
    }
}

namespace Namespace.ViewModel.Type
{
    public enum FooType
    {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue
    }
}
```

If the underlying integer values are the same or the values are in the same order in each enum, you can cast one enum explicitly to `int` and let the other be implicitly cast from the `int` value:

```
_fooService.All()
    .Select(x => new FooVM
    {
       FooName = x.FooName,
       Type = (int)x.Type,               
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your query. I just tested it. I'd check the entities returned by your service. You can run this in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    //create test list
    var fooService = new List<Foo>();
    var random = new Random();
    Enumerable.Range(0,30).ToList().ForEach(i => fooService.Add(new Foo(){Id=i,Type=(FooType)random.Next(0,3),FooName="Foo"+i}));

    //select view models
    fooService.Select(x => new FooVM
             {
               FooName = x.FooName,
               Type = x.Type
              }
        ).Dump();
}

public enum FooType
{
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue
}

public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public FooType Type { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
}

public class FooVM
{
  public FooType Type { get; set; }
  public string FooName { get; set; }
}
```